# Как взаимодействовать с Midjourney через python?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, discord, искусственный-интеллект

У меня есть подписка на Midjourney. Я хочу сделать бота на aiogram, который будет генерировать фотографии с Midjourney. Есть ли какой-то способ, кроме сторонних API по типу thenextleg.io? Взаимодействие с Midjourney происходит только через Discord.

Comment: Очевидно, использовать API Discord

Comment: У меня есть сервер в дс где стоит Midjourney. И путям отправки сообщений на этот сервер от лица пользователя получать изобржаения?

Comment: Да, а потом отправлять их в телеграмм

Comment: Это сложно осуществляется?

Comment: Думаю нет, просто изучи библиотеки

Comment: А вообще есть библиотеки для midjorney по типу [midjourney-py](https://pypi.org/project/midjourney-py/)

Comment: @WTFisGoingOn , В этой тоже библиотеке нужна апишка которую надо покупать(

Comment: И у них сайт не рабочий

Comment: так вы же написали, что у вас есть подписка

Comment: А, может там без подписки но я думаю что будет как в thenextleg,io .То есть покупаешь подписку mj и подписку их апишки и пользуешься ею

Answer (score 0):

Есть готовые апи под это дело, чтобы через aiogram принимать от пользователя текстовое описание какое изображение он хочет получить (prompt) и вызвать апи по типу [userapi.ai](https://userapi.ai) (это API прослойка для Midjourney), дожидаться отрисовки и через вебхуки, либо постоянно пингуя апи чтобы получать текущий статус задачи, как только она будет выполнена (status: done) - высылать ответ пользователю